# How to load a folder of Json files in Langchain?

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, document-loader

I am trying to load a folder of JSON files in Langchain as:

```
loader = DirectoryLoader(r'C:...')
documents = loader.load()
```

But I got such an error message:

> ValueError: Json schema does not match the Unstructured schema

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

I tried using `glob='**/*.json'`, but it is not working. The documentation on the Langchain website is limited as well.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to read the whole file, you can use `loader_cls` params:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader, TextLoader

loader = DirectoryLoader(DRIVE_FOLDER, glob='**/*.json', show_progress=True, loader_cls=TextLoader)
```

also, you can use `JSONLoader` with schema params like:

```
from langchain.document_loaders.json_loader import JSONLoader

DRIVE_FOLDER = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/demo"

loader = DirectoryLoader(DRIVE_FOLDER, glob='**/*.json', show_progress=True, loader_cls=JSONLoader, loader_kwargs = {'jq_schema':'.content'})

documents = loader.load()

print(f'document count: {len(documents)}')
print(documents[0] if len(documents) > 0 else None)
```

`jq_schema` You can follow this:
https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/master/langchain/document_loaders/json_loader.py#L10

more usage for `DirectoryLoader`: https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/master/langchain/document_loaders/directory.py

Comment: Got the following error. Any solution for this?
ValueError: Expected page_content is string, got <class 'NoneType'> instead.